# Android: Progressbar displayed

Tags: android, progress-bar

I want to display a progressbar, and during this time it's get items and when it's finished geting all the items, it will show the list.

How is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what about implementing a AsyncTask with ProgressDialog as a member?

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ProgressDialog.html

See the [article](http://it-projects.spb.ru/?p=150&lang=en).

Comment: Whta is the difference of using AsyncTask or regular progress threading?

Comment: so AsyncTask is better for some reasons?

Answer (score 0):

1. Create the `ProgressDialog` in your `Activity`:

   ```
   private ProgressDialog progressDialog;
   ```
2. Set the `ProgressDialog` in any action where you want to take some time:

   ```
   progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(FoodDriveModule.this, "", "Loading...");
   ```
3. Use `Thread` to handle the progress bar:

   ```
   new Thread() 
   {
       public void run() 
       {
           try
           {
               sleep(1500);
               // do some task (whatever you want to do)
           } 
           catch(Exception e)
           {
               Log.e("tag",e.getMessage());
           }
       }.start();
   }
   ```