# ProgressDialog in Android for new Activity

Tags: android, progressdialog

When the user taps a menu item I need to create a new Activity. This Activity loads a lot of data then shows a map and takes some seconds to be shown.
How can I use ProgressDialog from an activity to another? I actually cannot see it if I call

```
ProgressDialog dialog = ProgressDialog.show(this, "", "Loading. Please wait...", true);
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4077867/android-progressbar-displayed/4078156#4078156)

You should use your AsyncTask in onCreate() method of the Activity you start from menu.

Comment: I have the same issue, but I don't see how AsyncTask is used correctly.  It seems that the ProgressDialog doesn't start drawing until the new Activity is completely finished being created (through an AsyncTask).  By then the ProgressDialog is no longer needed.